# Why only the marker of the last input appears in Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-maps-markers

Hi, i'm using Google Places Autocomplete with 4 inputs, autocomplete works fine, but only the marker and infowindow of the last input appears. Can someone tell me where is the problem and why the markers and infowindows of other inputs don't appear on the map?
Any answer is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>

        <script>
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4700, 49.9600),
        zoom: 10,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);
    var autocompleteOptions = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "
az "
        }
    };

    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("
controlsInput ");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
            });
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }

            marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')].join(' ');
            }

            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function () {
            autocomplete.setTypes(types);
        });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <input id="pac-input" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter the pickup point"><br>
            <input id="pac-input2" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
            <input id="pac-input3" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
            <input id="pac-input4" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br><br>

        <div hidden="hidden" id="type-selector" class="controls">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
            <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

            <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
            <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

            <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
            <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 380px; "></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it be a closure issue? Try wrapping your for loop in a function and passing the variables in. I suspect your marker and info-window are being overwritten each time.

Comment: You only have one autocomplete object, it is left referencing the last input field. [working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_mutlipleAutocompleteA.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix it:

```
<script>
var map = null;
          var autocompleteOptions = {
           componentRestrictions: {country: "az"}
          };

function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i) {
            autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
            autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
              });  
              infowindow.close();
              marker.setVisible(false);
              var place = autocomplete[i].getPlace();
              if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
              }

              // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
              if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
              } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
              }

              marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
              }));
              marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
              marker.setVisible(true);

              var address = '';
              if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
              }

              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
}
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4700, 49.9600),
            zoom: 10,
            zoomControl:true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
              style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeControl:true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
            }
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
          var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);


          var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("controlsInput");
          var autocomplete = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
           setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i);
          }
          // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
          // Autocomplete.
          function setupClickListener(id, types) {
            var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
              for (var i=0 ; i<autocomplete.length; i++) {
                autocomplete[i].setTypes(types);
              }
            });
          }

          setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
          setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
          setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_mutlipleAutocompleteA.html)

Comment: Thanks! But there is a lttle problem: When an input field is changed, the previous marker doesn't disappear. I used to solve it like in my answer, but with no success

Comment: What "answer" are you referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer on my own question because of reputation
So here are the changes I have made:

`var map = null;

var infowindow = [];

var marker = [];`

Comment: ...
`function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i) {
            autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
            autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
              infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({`

Comment: If there isn't an "answer", please edit your question to include the updated code, or create a new question with the new problem.

Comment: Well, here is the new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341166/the-previous-marker-of-changed-input-field-doesnt-disappear-in-google-places-au)